# JUnit test case issue with fetching db connection along with play framework, spring jdbctemplate?

Tags: java, playframework, junit4, spring-jdbc

I am writing **JUnit Test case**, where the process trying to get DataSource it is getting the following error message.

**Stack Trace:**

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException
    at play.api.db.DB$.getDataSource(DB.scala:141)
    at play.api.db.DB.getDataSource(DB.scala)
    at play.db.DB.getDataSource(DB.java:22)
    at dao.BaseDao.getJdbcTemplate(BaseDao.java:13)
```

Here, I am using spring jdbctemplate, play framework and JUnit.
please find the following resource files which I am using.

**application.conf**

```
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xx.xx.xx.xx:1521/XE"
db.default.user=work
db.default.pass=work
......
```

**components.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="controllers,services,dao,org.springframework.jndi" />

</beans>
```

**BaseDao.java**

```
package dao;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import play.db.DB;

public class BaseDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        if (jdbcTemplate == null) {
            this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(DB.getDataSource("default"));
        }
        return this.jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

}
```

**PublishedReferenceYieldServiceImplTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:components.xml")
public class PublishedReferenceYieldServiceImplTest {
//Here I am accessing baseDAO
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're missing to load the context of the application. Check the play.test.Helpers package.

Try putting your actual test code inside the following block:

```
running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...your test here...
    }           
});
```